# What providerName and connectionStrings should be used for MS SQL Compact Edition in MVC 4 in Visual Studio 2013 in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

What `providerName` should be used in `Web.config` file for MS SQL Compact Edition in MVC 4 in Visual Studio 2013?

### Introduction


When I use:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

my website database works and `Genre` objects are retrieved from database and displayed

[image]

after I change of `providerName` to `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient` like this:

```
   <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
         providerName=providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

I get:

[image]

### So WHY I want to change anything?

### Actual problem:


If I leave `providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"` when I want to add new controller by this menu:

[image]

I get:

[image]

but if I set `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient` the `StoreManagerController` is generated but the database does not work at all.

Question: What should I do to generate `StoreManagerController`? I follow this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5 and link to the working project just before that step it: http://www.speedyshare.com/RGdqH/MvcMusicStore.zip

Comment: You have the correct provider; Just looks like a foul-up within the T4 of the controller. My guess would be to implement an empty controller and add the context, or spin it up on your local SQL Express and use `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: I am ASP.NET noob. I learn it from the basis. What should I do? Maybe reinstall something? This is the first place where the tutorial I gave link to at the bottom of OP is not working for me.

Comment: As an aside, you could try changing your connection string to something like: `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.mdf`. Give you're using MVC4 you may want to migrate towards using [LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx).

Comment: @BradChristie The tutorial Is based upon Compact Edition and everything what I did till now was made when the providerName was set to Compact edititon. The syntax or sth else with code is wrong with that:  `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.mdf`

Comment: @BradChristie Please look: http://postimg.org/image/4y3zw9fjz/eebadbe1/

Comment: Should be `<connectionStrings><add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>` (your database initializer may have to be re-executed)

Comment: @BradChristie This is awesome. You just ended my 2.5 hours long problem. Could You post it as answer? Is there any literature that I can read so I will know what conncetion strings use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So bare in mind the "Mvc Music Store" was MVC 101 since the beginning of MVC. Given there have been a lot of changes, the chances of the documentation/walk-throughts being a little off are unfavorable. With that said:

The T4 template for the data-driven controller is obviously failing due to your connection string. This is most likely because SQL Express (in it of itself) has gone through a lot of cycles and is now following [LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx). Given you're using MVC4, it's probably a good time to upgrade, and this means you can have all the benefits of SQL Express (including the `System.Data.SqlClient` provider) without the possible headaches from previous revisions.

With that said, change your connection string to use the new format:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
         connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.mdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And (probably) re-run your DatabaseInitializer (if I recall correctly, this should happen automatically since it's using EF. If not, you can go to your Package Manager console and run `Update-Database`).

This now gives you the provider the Controller template wants while still keeping it as a local (dev) database.

Comment: Follow-up: The connection string is based on what you're trying to accomplish. Obviosuly using MySQL/InnoDB/etc. you'd have to use their providers. However, in more current versions you're pretty much looking at `System.Data.SqlClient` with the `Data Source=` changing. it may be `SQLSERVER` (name of SQL computer), `SQLSERVER\SQLEXPRESS` (Sql Express instance off SQLSERVER), `(LocalDb)\v11` (local version of newer SQL Express), `.\SQLEXPRESS`, etc.

Comment: For non-development versions you'll provide `Initial Catalog=` (the name of the database). For the dev versions, you typically provide `AttachDbFileName=` (since it's a file-based database and not on a server). You can also use `|DataDirectory|` to reference you're project's local `App_Data` directory (for web projects).

Comment: As a side note, [LocalDB isn't a replacement for Sql Server Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx), it's a hybrid between Sql CE (which in my opinion is Deprecated) and Sql Server Express.  That is to say that LocalDB can be deployed with a .Net application (not as a side product), does not require SQL Server (Express) to be installed to work, but works exactly like Sql Server in terms of basic features (data types, sql syntax etc) unlike Sql CE.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: thank you for the clarification. I was probably vague in how I described it, but you're absolutely right. And it does provide a more seamless integration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the database your local server(make sure u do a back up off data / your seed method has relevant data needed)
2. Delete all migration class files besides the configuration file from your Migrations Folder. (migrations need to be enabled in order for this to work "Enable migrations" )
3. In the Package Manage Console type the following command: “ add-migration update   ”. Once that is successful
4. Type in “Update-Database” in the Package Manager Console.
5. Your Database will be recreated without ANY data.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem for MVC5,  so i change the web.comfig  connection string for:

```
 <add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.mdf Catalog=MvcMusicStore" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

it works for me!